# How does `make_shared` avoid double allocation and allow `release` to prolong the lifetime of the managed object beyond that of the shared_pointer?

Tags: c++, c++11, shared-ptr, std

`std::shared_ptr` can be implemented with two members, a pointer to the managed resource and a pointer to a control block.

`std::shared_ptr` can be constructed with `std::make_shared` which can combine the two allocations for the managed object and `shared_ptr` control block into one.

How does `release` then work? It allows the managed object to outlive the shared pointer but the control block must be deleted in the shared pointer's destructor. How is destruction and deallocation handled?

Comment: It doesn't work because it doesn't exist.

Comment: Thanks. I've been wracking my brains over how to implement this. It never occurred to me that `release` might not exist. `unique_ptr` has it, I presumed `shared_ptr` must have it too.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't `release` from a `shared_ptr`. It doesn't work. There is no such member.

Answer (score -1):

When the shared_ptr destructor is called, the shared refCount is decremented.  When the shared refCount reaches 0, the object is destroyed.  In the case of an object created with make_shared, the space for the object remains unused in the control block.  When the weak refCount reaches 0, the space is released back to the heap.

Comment: Does not address the question about `std::shared_ptr::release`. (Which admittedly does not exist, so the question is nonsense to begin with.)

Comment: 'nonsense' is harsh.